# Go back to fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have the following Activity code:-

```
public class legislator_info extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_legislator_info);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Legislator Info");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String bioguide = i.getExtras().getString("Person");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                // click on 'up' button in the action bar, handle it here
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

So basically I have a fragment which has a list view displayed in it. On click of a list Item I start this activity and I want to go back to the previous fragment on the back button click. I tried the above code but I am not able to travel back. Am pretty new at this any help is appreciated.

I have added my fragment in the following way:-

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
            LegislatorFragment lf = new LegislatorFragment();
            ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container,lf);
            ft.addToBackStack(null);
            ft.commit();
```

Comment: post your full code

Comment: full code of what?? I posted the full code for activity

Comment: didnt you manage on backpressed ?

Comment: follow standard Naming convention for class Names e.g. your class name should be `LegislatorInfo`

Comment: Do we need back pressed too??

Comment: @AnirbanMishra Soft Back button or you created any on your UI?

Comment: @rahulkapoor I added the following line and a back button showed up:-getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am still not clear what you want to achieve but you can try this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    finish();
}
```

EDIT:

```
case android.R.id.home:
            //call onBackPressed here
            onBackPressed();
            return true;
```

Comment: I just want to go back to the fragment I came from...in my previous fragment:-yourListView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {
                Person obj = (Person)yourListView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent intent = new Intent(ByState.this.getActivity(), legislator_info.class);
                intent.putExtra("Person",obj.getBioguide());
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: Yup It worked but I cannot accept the answer because of my reputation...thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AnirbanMishra `Reputation` doesn't matter on Accepting Answer you can accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override onOptionsItemSelected because you are trying with Action bar's back button.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case android.R.id.home:
        onBackPressed();
        return true;
}
return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Then override BackPressed -

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
 FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
 if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
      fm.popBackStack();
    }
 else {
 super.onBackPressed();
 }
}
```

Comment: Only Answer that helped me! Thx a lot my friend :)